# How make search web in laravel by ajax

Tags: ajax, laravel

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use DB;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class SearchController extends Controller
{
    public function search(Request $request) {
        $text = $request->input('text');

        $patients = DB::table('patients')
                        ->where('firstname', 'Like', $text)
                        ->get();

        // return the results
        return response()->json($patients);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

type your return in this way!

```
return response($patients);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   $filter = $request->tagname;
   $events = Event::where([
             ['status', '=', 1],
             ['search_tags','LIKE',"%{$filter}%"]
          ])->get();

   return response($events);
```

Comment: just you change variable name and selected model.